# Wrong result of sympy integration

Tags: sympy, symbolic-integration

This expression returns zero, but it shouldn`t.

```
P = x^6-14x^4+49x^2-36
```

```
integrate(1/P, (x, 1/3, 1/2))
```

I also used expand on expression, without any result.
Am i doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: Maybe you omit x = Symbol('x')

Comment: nope, here is full code   http://pastebin.com/3fakWGBA

Comment: I get a result numerically equivalent to the one by Mathematica. Do you know that 1/3 and 1/2 get evaluated to zero in Python 2.7? You should create a fraction by S.One/3, or Rational(1, 3). That is, make sure that you have a SymPy object before the division symbol.

Comment: I'd also suggest to paste directly your python code on stackoverflow, that will make it easier for people to find out what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
from sympy import *

x = symbols('x')
P = x**6-14*x**4+49*x**2-36
I = integrate(1/expand(P), (x, S.One/3, S.One/2))
```

I get the result:

```
In [5]: I
Out[5]: -3*log(3)/80 - log(7)/48 - log(2)/48 - log(8)/240 + log(10)/240 + log(4)/48 + 3*log(5)/80

In [6]: I.n()
Out[6]: -0.00601350282195297
```

In alternative, you could run the command *isympy -i*, this will run a SymPy prompt that converts all Python integers to SymPy integers before the input gets evaluated by the SymPy parser.

Python integer division is different between Python 2 and Python 3, the first returns and integer, the second returns a floating point number. Both versions are different to SymPy integer division, which returns fractions. To use SymPy division, you need to make sure that at least one among the dividend and divisor are SymPy objects.

Comment: Your answer is correct, i got same result in online compiler. Guess my 2.7 python is indeed source of problem. Thank you!

Comment: No, Python 2.7 is not the problem, it's just it wasn't designed in the beginning to act as a computer algebra system or numeric language.